# Swap value of two properties on object(s)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple function that will swap the values of two properties on the same or different global objects.

```
object1 = {"key 1":"value 1"};
object2 = {"key 2":"value 2"};

swapValuesInObject ("object1['key 1']","object2['key 2']",true)
// should result in:
// object1 === {"key 1":"value 2"};
// object2 === {"key 2":"value 1"};
```

Another example:

```
object1 = {"key 1":"value 1", "key 2":"value 2"};

swapValuesInObject ("object1['key 1']","object1['key 2']",1===1)
// should result in:
// object1 === {"key 1":"value 2", "key 2":"value 1"};
```

Here's what I've been able to come up with so far, but it's not much. Getting hung up on how to do the assignment.

```
function swapValuesInObject(property1, property2, condition) {
    if (condition) {
        // temp assignment
        var Obj1Value = property1;

        // do the switcheroo
        array1 = array2Value;
        array2 = array1Value;
    }
    return true;
};
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
var obj1 = {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "Value2"
};
var obj2 = {
    "key3" : "value3",
    "key4" : "Value4"
};

function swap(sourceObj, sourceKey, targetObj, targetKey) {
    var temp = sourceObj[sourceKey];
    sourceObj[sourceKey] = targetObj[targetKey];
    targetObj[targetKey] = temp;
}

swap(obj1, "key1", obj1, "key2");
swap(obj1, "key1", obj2, "key4");
```

Answer (score 14):

With ES6 destructuring, you can now swap without a temp variable. This applies to not only swapping variable values as in `[a, b] = [b, a]` but more complex expressions involving properties of objects, like so: `[obj.key1, obj.key2] = [obj.key2, obj.key1]`.  To avoid more redundancy, you need to use a swap function:

```
function swap(obj, key1, key2) {
   [obj[key1], obj[key2]] = [obj[key2], obj[key1]];
}
swap(obj, 'key1', 'key2');
```

The same idea applies with two objects and two keys:

```
function swap(obj1, key1, obj2, key2) {
   [obj1[key1], obj2[key2]] = [obj2[key2], obj1[key1]];
}
swap(obj1, 'key1', obj2, 'key2');
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple words,

```
var obj = {
 "key1": "value1",
 "key2": "Value2" 
}
```

to assign **value1** to **key2** & **value2** to **key1**

```
[obj['key1'], obj['key2']] = [obj['key2'], obj['key1']];
```