# Using replace values between two json objects with rxjs in angular

Tags: json, angular, rxjs

I want to use Rxjs map() method to switch values between two json objects. Or if there are any better rxjs methods I am open to suggestions

For example if I have two json objects:

```
[{"firstname":"abc","lastname":"bcd"},{"firstname":"xyz","lastname":"zzz"}]
```

How do I for example switch the values of first name from both json objects in the array as well as the lastnames? I am very new to rxjs!

Thanks!

Comment: Does your `Observable` emit `{"firstname":"abc","lastname":"bcd"}`, then `{"firstname":"abc","lastname":"bcd"}`, or does it emit `[{"firstname":"abc","lastname":"bcd"},{"firstname":"xyz","lastname":"zzz"}]` all at once?

Comment: It emits it all at once currently.

Comment: what is the desire output? switch both the firstname and the lastname?

Comment: So basically switching both JSON objs ? x)

Comment: Could you please add the desired output to your question.

Comment: ... and what you have actually tried to achieve this. This is not a coding service ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, swapping the entire objects will work:

```
let swapped = observable.pipe(map(([first, second]) => [second, first]));
```

In older versions of JS (and made a bit verbose on purpose):

```
function swapPair(arr) {
    var first = arr[0];
    var second = arr[1];
    return [second, first];
}

var swapped = observable.pipe(map(swapPair));
```

---

If you want a more generic way to swap properties -- I was about to write something, but really it's been done before:

- [Swap value of two properties on object(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224987/swap-value-of-two-properties-on-objects)
- [Swapping two properties of objects with function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574428/swapping-two-properties-of-objects-with-function-in-javascript)